# Python How to check if a DataFrame column in pandas contain all the numbers in a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a list of lists for min-max values for each column . Now I want to check if for each column in my data frame , all the range values between min - max are in that column.

For example if my range is 1-5, I want to check that I have at least 1 showing of each number between 1-5 in my column.

I'd love if someone can help me out figure the best way to check it , I saw a few things online which didn't fit what I was looking for so any help will be welcomed !

min-max list : [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [101, 103], [203, 206], [2, 3], [1, 1]]

self.df_smalltrain - is my data frame (ignore the zeroes i don't count 0 as min)
[image: ![enter image description here]

and i want the output to be which numbers in the min-max range are not actually showing in the list
so it'll be a list of lists with the numbers that aren't showing for each column

output : [[2] ,[4],....]

My basic code so far:

```
 def prepare_unique_data(self):
    for (column_name,column_data) in self.df_smalltrain.iteritems():
        print('Column Name : ', column_name)
        print('Column Contents : ', column_data.values)

    for i in range(len(self.min_max)):
        min = self.min_max[i][0]
        max = self.min_max[i][1]
        print(f"{min}  {max} ")
```

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output to this question.

Comment: @ScottBoston i've added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function to achieve that, you need to give it the *column_data* and the proper *max* and *min values*

```
def prepare_unique_data(self):
    for [min, max], col in zip(self.min_max, self.df_smalltrain.columns):
        assert self.value_range_exists(self.df_smalltrain[col], min, max)

def value_range_exists(self, series, min_value, max_value):
   current_values = series.unique()
   expected_values = list(range(min_value, max_value + 1))
   return set(current_values) == set(expected_value)
```

Comment: when trying to implement in i came across this bug : AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unique' . what might cause it ? I called the function like so :   print(self.value_range_exists(column_data.values, min, max))

Comment: I've updated it, now you'll get an exception if one of the columns does not respect your condition. Be aware that self.min_max, self.df_smalltrain.columns should have the same length